# How to enable DNS over HTTPS for the public DNS route in EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https

I am working on a Facebook bot app. A requirements is to setup a webbook on my webserver to return a token, to validate my account.

I configured a micro instance (Ubuntu) and created a web server (Express.js, Node.js, Nginx (proxy_pass)).

I allowed port 443 in the inbound traffic of the security group on this server.

The problem is they require *HTTPS* enabled on the webhook endpoint.

How to make this happen with the normal AWS DNS they provide you, without needing to setup a domain and my own SSL cert?

so that this would work:

**https**://ec2-52-90-117-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Put Cloudfront in front of it.

Comment: Alternatively, get free SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt.

Comment: And I would configure my Nginx with that free SSL cert?

Comment: By following one of the dozens of Let's Encrypt + nginx tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks! Just for clarification. I do need the SSL cert also if I am not intending to hook up my instance with a top level domain? and rather just use the AWS public DNS?

Comment: SSL has absolutely nothing to with DNS.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same. I need to call public DNS with https but I don't see how to implement a certificate with CloudFront without using Route53... And I must disagree with @ceejayoz comment saying that "SSL has absolutely nothing to with DNS". In AWS I would say it is rather the oposite, all HTTPS requests are one way or another related to a DNS record through Route53, CloudFront, ELB or ALB. If Amazon provide SSL for public urls on S3 why they don't do the same on EC2?

Comment: @RafaSashi The SSL part of CloudFront still has nothing to do with DNS, really; you do need a DNS record pointing to the CloudFront distribution, sure, but the SSL part is independent. They provide it for S3 because it's a managed service; you're responsible for your own setup on EC2.

Comment: You can create a self-signed certificate
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the domain name you from from AWS, but you can't avoid using externally issued SSL certs. Trusted SSL certificates, can be only issed by external entities, the one you make for yourself will not make it.

Comment: I understand. I am beginner in terms of HTTPs and SSL and my problem is that I thought the SSL cert needs to be attached to a domain that I own, but if I understand you correctly I can also use the domain name from AWS when setting up my SSL cert, right?

Comment: if you don't want to have an own domain name, you can request a cert on the aws one

Answer (score 0):

you can get a free ssl cert issued by startssl. it works well with EC2 and easy to setup.

https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=1

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for your reply. To understand you correctly, that means I have to setup the ssl cert for my own domain right?

I was hoping that I can enable HTTPS for the URL that Amazon give me (like this one http://ec2-52-90-117-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com ).

Heroku supports Https by default and I thought AWS offers something similar.

Comment: Sorry this setup is a bit confusing for me. I am new in this dev ops world :)
To rephrase:
Amazon provides some URL for my instance. My instance is a https server (nginx) that listens for port 80 and not 433 yet. I understand that I have to configure nginx for SSL, which requires a SLL cert right? 

I always thought I need to issue the SSL to some sort domain?

Comment: @BausNauf Putting a domain name or a IP inside is up to you and depends on your use case, requirements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer an alternative to StartSSL. You might want to try Certbot. It will take care of issuing the certificate, updating your Nginx config, and automatically renews your free certificates before they expire.

On a related note, you may want to register a domain or get an Elastic IP for your webhook. The reason is when your EC2 instance restarts for some reason, it will generate a new public IP *and* AWS hostname. If that happens, you'll need to update your webhook configuration on Facebook.

If your chatbot is still in the development process, you may want to check out *ngrok*. You can run it locally on your machine and it will accept HTTP & HTTPS requests. The best part is you don't have to pay for AWS hosting. Once your chatbot is ready, you can deploy it on AWS EC2 and get a certificate.